# How to Update Room Quantity?

Tags: java, arrays

Currently, I want to update my room availability after a booking added to the database, but the problem I am facing now is, I don't know how to update the Room quantity after making a booking.

The solution I need is, when I key in the room quantity and I add, the room database will minus the room quantity.

### Room DA

```
public boolean updateRoomQuantity(String roomID, int amountOfRoomLeft){
    String sql = String.format("update room set roomAvailability =%d where roomID = '%s'", amountOfRoomLeft, roomID);
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RoomDA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Booking DA

```
public boolean addRecord(String booID, String booDate, String booTime, String roomID, double roomPrice, int duration, String memberID,
        String receptionistID, String checkinStatus, double totalRoomPrice, double totalPrice) {
    String sql = String.format("insert into booking values('%s','%s','%s','%s',%.2f,%d,'%s','%s','%s',%.2f,%.2f)", booID, booDate, booTime, roomID, roomPrice, duration, memberID, receptionistID, checkinStatus, totalRoomPrice, totalPrice);
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BookingDA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Booking Panel Add Button

```
private void addBooking() {
    double total = 0.0;
    int roomQuantity= Integer.parseInt(jtfRoomQuantity.getText().trim());
    double price = Double.parseDouble(jtfRoomPrice.getText().trim());

    total = (roomQuantity* price);
    jtfTotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    jtfTotalRoomPrice.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    if (!emptyFields()) {
        if (jcbAutoFillDate.isSelected()) {
            jbtFillInDate.doClick();
        }
        String booID = jtfBookingID.getText();
        String booDate = jtfBookingDate.getText();
        String booTime = jtfBookingTime.getText();
        String roomID = null;
        Room room = roomDA.getRecordByName(jtfAutoCompleteRoom.getText());
        double roomPrice = Double.parseDouble(jtfRoomPrice.getText());
        String memberID = null;
        Member member = memberDA.getRecordByName(jtfAutoCompleteMember.getText());
        String receptionistID = receptionistDA.getRecordByName(jcbAvailableReceptionist.getSelectedItem().toString()).getReceptionistID();
        String checkinStatus = jcbStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
        double totalRoomPrice = Double.parseDouble(jtfTotalRoomPrice.getText());
        double totalPrice = Double.parseDouble(jtfTotalPrice.getText());

        memberID = member.getMemberID();
        roomID = room.getRoomID();

        if (bookingDA.addRecord(booID, booDate, booTime, roomID, roomPrice, duration, memberID, receptionistID, checkinStatus, totalRoomPrice, totalPrice)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully added");
            refreshTableContent();
            autoResizeTable();
            reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AnyOne please help me link it ..Very Thank you

Comment: maybe you can add a trigger on DB?

Comment: How? Any solution for me to add a trigger?

Comment: Best would be to have `addRecord()` and `updateRoomQuantity()` in the _same_ transaction. I'm trying to understand your model: in the `room` table, how can a `roomID` be related to `amountOfRoomLeft`? In the logic, it seems you can book _several_ rooms. In case of 2 rooms booked do you intend to call twice the `updateRoomQuantity`?... can you provide the description of the `room` table?

Comment: I currently have 2 database 1 is for booking and 1 is for room.So when i key in the room quantity in the booking panel,after added,the room database ,room quantity will decrease.I have this problem right now.

Comment: Now i explain,i do it like a stock and purchase order.
room = stock,
booking  = purchase

Answer (score 0):

> use roomAvailability =roomAvailability -1

```
public boolean updateRoomQuantity(String roomID, int amountOfRoomLeft){
        String sql = String.format("update room set roomAvailability =roomAvailability-1 where roomID = '%s'", roomID);
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RoomDA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Before Adding New Record check whether availability is greter than 0. if it is greter than zero allocate a room. else allocate another room.

Answer (score 0):

In your Booking DA your are inserting new bookings, so you have also Room DA which updates the amount of room left.

`roomDA.updateRoomQuantity(roomId, amountOfRoomLeft);`

roomId exists in your bookingDA the only left unknown variable is amountOfRoomLeft. Therefore you should write a new method which gets the amounttOfRoomLeft

Something like:

`public int getRoomQuantity(String roomID){
    String sql = String.format("select roomAvailability from room where roomID = '%s'", roomID);
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset = stmt.execute(sql);
        resultset.next();
        return resultset.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RoomDA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}`

You should also do your homeworks on your own :))